# "No Access control header is present" - while calling AWS lambda function through API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, es6-promise

I have created a Lambda function in python, inside this function I have put header with cross origin details. Here is the code of my Lambda function:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):    
    data=''
    s3_boto = boto3.client('s3')
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    reference_elements = event['data1']
    test_elements = event['data2']
    try:
        #access first event object
        imagePath = []        
        data= compute_data(reference_elements, test_elements)
        return response({'message': data}, 200)      

    except Exception as e:
        return e
    return response({'message': data}, 200)

def response(message, status_code):
     return {
        'statusCode': str(status_code),
        'body': json.dumps(message),
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET"
            },
        }
```

Now I have created a AWS API Gateway with POST method and enable CORS. Then I deployed this API.
While I am running this API from Postman it is working fine.
But once I try to fetch this API from my React JS code it is throwing the following error: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwjEi.png)

Here is my React Js code in button click:

```
let postData = {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}
const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(postData)
    }
    const url =
      "https://apiId.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/apiFunctionName"
    fetch(url, requestOptions)
      .then(response => console.log(response))
      .then(data => console.log(data))
```

Please correct me where I am going wrong, I have invested lots of time for trial and error but no luck.

Comment: Can u see if your `OPTIONS` preflight call is getting a 200 with the proper CORS headers?

Comment: `"Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*" is a **response** header, it has no place being on the request.

Comment: I have also tried with 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', in request, still no luck

Comment: What @Quentin is trying to say is all `Access-Control-Allow` headers are response headers. Don't send them in the request

Comment: Yes I have removed that part. Now my javascript request code looks like this:       `const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(postData)
    }
    const url =
      "https://awsId.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/calculateHomography"
    fetch(url, requestOptions)
      .then(response => console.log(response.json()))
      .then(data => console.log(data)) `      but still I am getting the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Browsers before making a call to a cross origin, makes a `preflight` request using the `OPTIONS` method. In your network tab, you should be seeing an `OPTIONS` call, which in your case is not allowed on `ApiGateway`. Similar to the `POST` method you have allowed on gateway, allow `OPTIONS` call. Return the OPTIONS call with a `200` and the `CORS` headers, based on which domain you want to allow.

Comment: can you give me screenshot how do I  make a preflight request using the OPTIONS method

Comment: You don't need to make a `preflight` request. Browser makes that call to make sure you are allowed to make whatever request you are planning to make actually. So when you attempt a post, a preflight request will be made, and if the response of the preflight has `POST` in the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` reponse header and origin is correct, the actual request will be made. You should also be seeing CORS exceptions on your console if this call returns non 200 or headers don't match. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request

Comment: I am getting the cors error in console, but in network section cant find any OPTIONS message.  in console I am getting these errors only: "Access to fetch at 'https://awsId.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/calculateData' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
 POST https://awsId.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/calculateData net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: In network XHR section when the Api is calling I am getting this Response Headers:     `content-length: 235
content-type: application/json
date: Wed, 01 Apr 2020 05:16:55 GMT
status: 200
x-amz-apigw-id: KSqG8FrhoAMFnNg=
x-amzn-requestid: 2d2dddbe-e9c7-4584-bef5-7dd0b2d694c8
x-amzn-trace-id: Root=1-5e8423c5-148589d6a476b17cf9d53385;Sampled=0 `

Comment: I have installed Moesif Cors changer plugin for chrome and make it ON, now my API call is working fine from localhost, but I need to check it after deploying in sagemaker.